# Mongodb aggregate grouping elements of an array type field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have below data in my collection:

```
[
    {
        "_id":{
            "month":"Jan",
            "year":"2022"
        },
        "products":[
            {
                "product":"ProdA",
                "status":"failed",
                "count":15
            },
            {
                "product":"ProdA",
                "status":"success",
                "count":5
            },
            {
                "product":"ProdB",
                "status":"failed",
                "count":20
            },
            {
                "product":"ProdB",
                "status":"success",
                "count":10
            }
        ]
    },
...//more such data
]
```

I want to group the elements of products array on the name of the product, so that we have record of how what was the count of failure of success of each product in each month. Every record is guaranteed to have both success and failure count each month. The output should look like below:

```
[
    {
        "_id":{
            "month":"Jan",
            "year":"2022"
        },

        "products":[
            {
                "product":"ProdA","status":[{"name":"success","count":5},{"name":"failed","count":15}]
            },
            {
                "product":"ProdB","status":[{"name":"success","count":10},{"name":"failed","count":20}]
            }
         ]
    },
    ...//data for succeeding months
]
```

I have tried to do something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $unwind: "$products" },
{
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            month: "$_id.month",
            year: "$_id.year"
        },
        products: { $push: { "product": "$product", status: { $push: { name: "$status", count: "$count" } } } }
    }
}]);
```

But above query doesn't work.

On which level I need to group fields so as to obtain above output.
Please help me to find out what I am doing wrong.

Thank You!

Comment: Is it even possible using aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

Your first group stage needs to group by both the `_id` and the product name, aggregate a list of status counts and then another group stage which then forms the products list:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$products"},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        id: "$_id",
        product: "$products.product",
      },
      status: {
        $push: {
          name: "$products.status",
          count: "$products.count"    
        }        
      }      
    }    
  },
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.id",
      products: {
        $push: {
          product: "$_id.product",
          status: "$status"
        }        
      }      
    }    
  }  
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IwPZvuD3UNy)